# Position jQuery Tools overlay next to trigger

Tags: jquery, position, offset, jquery-tools, css-position

I want to have multiple overlays with multiple triggers all with the same class `opener` with jQuery Tools and apple effect. How can I position the overlays next to their triggers? I have tried

```
$('button.opener').click(function() {
      var positionx = $('#' + this.id).offset().left;
      example("#item").overlay({
 left: positionx,
```

but it only works the first time it is opened. would really, really appreciate the any help.
here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FHKVW/
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `left` position outside of the initial config. For some reason, the re-running of `.overlay` doesn't override the config settings. This should work:

```
var example = jQuery.noConflict();
$('button.opener').click(function () {
    var positionx = $('#' + this.id).offset().left;
    example("#item").overlay({
        left: positionx,
        top: 100,
        closeOnClick: false,
        load: false,
        effect: 'apple',
        speed: 1000,
        oneInstance: false,
        fixed: false,
    });
    //add this line
    example('#item').overlay().getConf().left = positionx;

   (example('#item').overlay().isOpened() == true) ? example('#item').overlay().close() : example('#item').overlay().load();
});
```

Comment: thank you so  much I spent three days trying to get this to work :) thanks